# is it possible to get all documents using criteria on two fields with a max date

Tags: database, mongodb, filter, criteria

I have documents in a 'merge' collection with flat structure and a huge number of 'fields' (more than 100).

Amongst those fields have 'partNumber', and 'date' which are not unique.

I am newbie in mongo, I need to retrieve all documents (and all their fields, without needing to list them explicitely in a project stage), but selecting only the records which have the latest date for a given partNumber (and this for all partNumbers).
Is that possible in mongoDB 3.2 ? What would be the query ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, Do you want to know MongoDB query for this thing? Or Are you using any backend programming language ?

Comment: I am using python and pymongo, and yes I am interested int he query. The collection is quite big, so performance can be a driver for the solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20892218)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I will do it next time onwards, note that the question is edited after providing the answer. and i've provided a sort of answer. Thank you for the review

Answer (score 0):

After struggling on complex aggregation queries, I found a KISS solution with some code and only 2 queries:
- 1 aggregation query to retrieve couples partNumber, most recent date

```
db.getCollection('merge').aggregate(
   [
     { $group : { _id : "$partNumber", maxdate: { $max: "$date" } } }
   ]
)
```

- Then in python, a single find query using all tuples parsed from previous step with (partNumber = partNumber1 and date = date1) or (partNumber = partNumber2 and date = date 2) or ...

Performs very fast.